# How to detect undock, dock or split is pressed on iPad (iOS 5)

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextview

I am trying to detect dock key is pressed or not on my iPad. This dock key is a new feature in iOS 5. When this key is pressed the keyboard disappears. I need to detect it. When this key is pressed I need to change the frame of my view, but I couldn't get any event by pressing this key.

I am trying to use the following function:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    NSLog(@"TEXT: %@", text);
    return YES;
}
```

When I pressed 'A' this function is called and print TEXT: A, but when dock key is pressed, this function wasn't called!

Is there a way to detect dock key on iPad? For clarification, the dock key is available on iPad (only in iOS 5) at the bottom right corner of the keyboard.

**ANSWER::::**

I used the following code in viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

and I got the event in method -(void)keyboardWillHide

```
-(void)keyboardWillHide
{
    NSLog(@"Pressed...");
}
```

thanks borrrden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user presses the dock key, you will be notified via the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification from NSNotificationCenter.