# Custom iOS keyboard repositioned by undocked system keyboard

Tags: ios, uikeyboard

Is it possible to prevent a custom keyboard from being repositioned by undocking a system keyboard?

If not, is it possible to add support for moving and docking to a custom keyboard?

Thanks,
alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undocking by longPress then move is a default gesture of iPad keyboard (default and custom) if  undocking setting is on.

With custom keyboard, this gesture assign to right lower conner of keyboard.

Check when undock keyboard from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009444/how-to-detect-undock-dock-or-split-is-pressed-on-ipad-ios-5) and resign or modify you custom keys.