# How to switch from custom keyboard to system keyboard?

Tags: ios

I have created a custom view  called **emojiKeyboardView**. If I want to use the custom keyboard, I could use `textView.inputView = emojiKeyboardView`.
But How could I switch back to the system keyboard?

Comment: see so answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996026/custom-ios-keyboard-repositioned-by-undocked-system-keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set textView.inputView to nil

```
[textView resignFirstResponder];
textView.inputView = nil;
[textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

or if you want to handle switching the keyboard even when your textView is not currently the first responder you could do something like this in your method to switch the keyboard:

```
BOOL isCurrentFirstResponder = [textView isFirstResponder];
if (isCurrentFirstResponder)
    [textView resignFirstResponder];

textView.inputView = nil;

if (isCurrentFirstResponder)
    [textView becomeFirstResponder];
```